# A snippet to monitor the last INSERT/UPDATE in an Oracle DB from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm looking for a simple, sample snippet of C# code to monitor an Oracle database and basically check for its last update. It could be either command line (great for future integration with Nagios) or GUI. I've did some prototypes but the code tend to get lengthy as I'm still kind of learning the language.

Any suggestion/comment would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Lord Burner: Sure sir, I need to monitor a set of tables, there's some apps inserting records there and since the data itself is somewhat descriptive, then I'd be able to do checks with relatively simple select statements . I guess the key is play with timestamps and last_update records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is:

1. Add a DATE field that represents the last update time to MY_TABLE table.

   `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (last_update_time DATE);`
2. Create an index on that field.

   `CREATE INDEX i_my_table_upd_time ON my_table (last_update_time);`
3. Create a database trigger on that table that fires ON UPDATE and ON INSERT and stores SYSDATE into the new field.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_table_insert_trg  
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  
   ON my_table  
   FOR EACH ROW  
   BEGIN  
      :new.last_update_time := SYSDATE;  
   END;
   ```

Now you can issue the following query every 5 minutes

```
SELECT max(last_update_time) FROM my_table;
```

and it will give you the time when your table was last updated.

There is no easy way to get a notification from Oracle, sorry.